# Optimization of a functional with linear kinks

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, optimization

This is a follow-up from my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394678/optimization-of-functional/2399806?noredirect=1#comment4954340_2399806), which was answered nicely. The new question is as follows:

I am looking to maximize a functional for $q(\theta)$ of the following form: $$ \max_{q(\cdot)} \int p(\theta) q (\theta) - \min\{d-q(\theta),0\} \; \mathrm{d} \theta$$ subject to $$ \int q(\theta) \; \mathrm{d} \theta = c$$ where $p(\theta) \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $\theta \in [0,1]$, $q(\theta) \in [a,b]$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}_+$, and boundary conditions are such that $q(0) = a$, $q(1)=b$.

This is similar to the last question, but now the integrand has various kinks depending on the value of $\theta$. I am wondering how to characterize the solutions to this problem (e.g. bang-bang?) and how this would extend to multiple dimensions if $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n)$ and $q$ was a vector-valued function.

My particular problem has the additional constraint that $q(\theta)$ is non-decreasing, but I am curious to know if this is solvable without this condition. Thanks!

Comment: I only just noticed that since $q(\theta) \in [a,b]$, we have $\min\{a - q(\theta), 0\} = a - q(\theta)$, which reduces the functional to $\int (p(\theta) + 1)q(\theta) - a \;\mathrm{d}\theta$. Is that really what you had in mind?

Comment: No not at all. Thanks for the catch. I've edited accordingly